# using httphandlers vs. asmx vs. wcf for JSON services for performance reasons?

Tags: wcf, web-services, json, asmx, httphandler

I need to build a service that would handle fairly simple JSON messages (about a dozen operations total). I'm anticipating a huge amount of usage, however so I want maximum performance and minimum overhead.

Would building this out as an HTTPHandler make any sense? Would it be appreciably/quantifiably more performant than ASMX or WCF?

Answer (score 1):

The closer you get to the actual HTTP request the less overhead you will have from a framework like WCF. So an HTTPHandler makes sense.

Now if it really matters is another question. The network overhead is most likely going to be much larger and you are not going to see a big difference in performance from a client. And with a big load you might need the WCF throttling behaviors to avoid overloading your servers with peak loads,

Comment: No, the network overhead of the network depends on the messages, not the backend technology. But WCF allows you to throttle request resulting in better scalability with heavy loads.